# React Native App Install But does not Open

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app that builds and installs successfully. However, it does not run. When I click to open it, it shows a white screen for a second then closes itself. Attached is a screenshot of the terminal when I run `react-native run-android`

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: is metro bundle is running?\

Comment: Yes it's running on a different terminal

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly related to native side errors you can debug that by using android studio and try running the project in studio you will get the errors in log cat of android studio